# https Azure websites return SEC_ERROR_OCSP_INVALID_SIGNING_CERT when accessed via Firefox

Tags: azure, firefox, certificate

I've noticed a problem today when accessing our **https://** `azurewebsites.net` websites in Firefox.

The following sites *(and I suspect any https azurewebsites.net site)* fail on Firefox :

- https://easytees.azurewebsites.net/
- https://easyfurniture.azurewebsites.net/
- https://hello.azurewebsites.net/    (not one of ours)

returning :

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to easyfurniture.azurewebsites.net. Invalid OCSP signing certificate in OCSP response. Error code: SEC_ERROR_OCSP_INVALID_SIGNING_CERT
>
> - The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
> - Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

The sites work fine in Chrome, Safari, and Tor browsers.

---

Why do **`https://*.azurewebsites.net`** fail in this way in Firefox?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a website hosting issue/outage by Microsoft.

Comment: Yet you have also provided a very useful answer -- thank you for that -- do you suggest posting a question like in a particular different forum / place?

Comment: @Jaxidian The question may still be interesting for people who want to generally understand the problem and whether it is safe to just use a different browser when they see this problem again elsewhere. I do agree, though, that StackOverflow is not the right place. Is it possible to move questions to other sites, such as ServerFault, SuperUser, etc.?

Comment: @FlorianWinter Honestly, I'm not sure where the correct place is for this question. I know it's not here but I also know the value it provides to people, hence why I both voted to close the question while also answering it. Somebody more familiar with the Stack Exchange network will have to answer your question. If you want more info on why FireFox only, you'd have to better understand how it handles & validates OCSP certs (i.e. it is stricter, in a good way, than other browsers although this is not something I'm very educated on).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Microsoft has an active issue with this. Try going to https://microsoft.com or https://portal.azure.com in Firefox and you see the same behavior.

Open tickets:

- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/12163379/
- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/62465/receiving-a-sec-error-ocsp-invalid-signing-cert-wh.html

Expired certificate: https://twitter.com/vcsjones/status/869033508114661376

Comment: https://microsoft.com is working fine on firefox

Comment: Interesting ... still not working in my Firefox browser ... perhaps they have fixed it and it is in the process of propagating around the internet right now ...

Comment: The blob storage service has same problem and they haven't fixed it

Comment: any sources on this?

Comment: @Jaxidian: Do you have a link to the issue

Comment: Expired certificate: https://twitter.com/vcsjones/status/869033508114661376